# Oracle database not getting updated using jsp.It's showing a blank page

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jsp

The problem is that when I enter the details in the form and enter submit, it shows a blank .jsp page and the database doesn't get updated either.I have included the odjbc.14 jar file in the WEB-INF/lib folder and am using oracle 10g. IDE-eclipse. What's wrong in the code??

This is the page to connect to database(oracle):

```
<body>
<%
    String user = request.getParameter("login_id");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
    String fname = request.getParameter("first_name");
String lname = request.getParameter("last_name");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String sql="INSERT INTO     MEMEBERS(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,USER_ID,PASSWORD,REG_DATE)values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"','"+user+"','"+pwd+"',CURDATE())";
try{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:nishtha/FirstJ2ee@//localhost:1521/XE");
  int action=con.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
  con.setAutoCommit(true);
if(action>=1){
    out.println("saved");
}
else{
    out.println("not saved");
}

}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you faced any exception or error?

Comment: "_What's wrong in the code?_" SQL injections.

Comment: @it-nish Use sysdate instead of curdate for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

The problem for the blank page is that your SQL is invalid and throws a SQLException. Your code ends up in the `catch` block and prints the error probably into the app server log rather than into your page. There are several things in your example that you could do better as explained further below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.sql.*,java.security.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
  String user = request.getParameter("login_id");    
  String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
  String fname = request.getParameter("first_name");
  String lname = request.getParameter("last_name");
  String email = request.getParameter("email");
  String sql = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, USER_ID, PASSWORD, REG_DATE)"
        + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE)";
  try {
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     Connection con = DriverManager
           .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:nishtha/FirstJ2ee@//localhost:1521/XE");
     con.setAutoCommit(false);
     PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     stmt.setString(1, fname);
     stmt.setString(2, lname);
     stmt.setString(3, email);
     stmt.setString(4, user);

     MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
     md.update(pwd.getBytes("UTF-8"));
     byte[] digest = md.digest();
     stmt.setString(5, new String(digest, "UTF-8"));

     int action = stmt.executeUpdate();
     if (action >= 1) {
        con.commit();
        out.println("saved");
     } else {
        out.println("not saved");
     }

  } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     out.println("Error saving your details:<br/>");
     out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

1.) **Better error handling:** As said, your error most likely ends up in the app server log. That may be absolutely fine as you may not want to print stack traces and random errors all over your web pages but with a little bit better error handling you can present this nicely back to the user and print it into the app server log. For example if you change

```
catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to the code below than you will start seeing error messages on your page as well as printing them into the app server log:

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    out.println("Error saving your details:<br/>");
    out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

2.) **Correct SQL statement:** After running your example above (note, I've corrected the typo in the table and called it `MEMBERS`), I get the error `ORA-00904: "CURDATE": invalid identifier`. As already mentioned in a comment you will need `SYSDATE` rather than `CURDATE`:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO     MEMBERS(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,USER_ID,PASSWORD,REG_DATE)values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"','"+user+"','"+pwd+"',SYSDATE)";
```

Now I get the expected result: `saved`

Note: `SYSDATE` is a keyword and therefore doesn't require any `()`. But there is still more!

3.) **Committing your data:** As mentioned in the other answer, you are not necessarily committing your data. It may works fine because AutoCommit has a default value of `true` or it may work fine after the first invocation of your page because you have set AutoCommit to `true` but in either case you may have some very bad side effects that can become tricky to debug. The best way to ensure your data is safe is by committing it explicitly yourself by changing

```
int action=con.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
con.setAutoCommit(true);
if(action>=1){
  out.println("saved");
}
```

to execute an actual commit and only when I also have done an insert:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
int action = con.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
if (action >= 1) {
    con.commit();
    out.println("saved");
} else {
    out.println("not saved");
}
```

This may gives you now a `Could not commit with auto-commit set on` as it does on my system because AutoCommit is set to `true` by default. So I deactivate this explicitly by adding an extra line:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

4.) **Prevent [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and poor performance:** One of the worst things you can ever do is to concatenate values directly into your SQL statements! This is very poor for Oracle performance as the database will always have to hard parse your statement and use more CPU doing so but it's even worse for security because now somebody can put in actual SQL statements in what's meant to be a single value. The remedy for that is to use bind variables:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, USER_ID, PASSWORD, REG_DATE)"
        + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE)";
try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:nishtha/FirstJ2ee@//localhost:1521/XE");
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, fname);
    stmt.setString(2, lname);
    stmt.setString(3, email);
    stmt.setString(4, user);
    stmt.setString(5, pwd);

    int action = stmt.executeUpdate();
    if (action >= 1) {
        con.commit();
        out.println("saved");
    } else {
        out.println("not saved");
    }
```

5.) **Obfuscate passwords:** This is another security concern. Storing passwords in clear text is bad, very bad indeed. You don't need to know your users password and nor should a DBA be able to get it either by just doing a simple `SELECT` on your table. Nor should the Unix or storage admin by grepping it out of the data files and nor the network admin by seeing it flying over the network in clear text. Ideally you encrypt your password as soon as possible, in this case I will apply a simply SHA-256 hash over it. Then on the login page I would make sure to again convert the password into a SHA-256 hash and compare the hashes rather than clear text passwords:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update(pwd.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] digest = md.digest();
stmt.setString(5, new String(digest, "UTF-8"));

int action = stmt.executeUpdate();
```